# Lag in displaying data from Oberver on LiveData

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-room, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I'm using a ViewModel that populates a RecyclerView.Adapter, and loads data from LiveData from my Room database. The problem is that my display is always blank, and checking with the Dao (for debug, on the main thread) shows me that the data is retreived just fine. (ergo there is data in the DB).

The problem is that the Observer on my LiveData always returns a null (or no data) and I end up having to refresh the fragment at least once (by moving away and moving back) to see anything - even the meagre one record I put in the Database for testing.

Restarting the app or fragment means a blank screen and a few refreshes before I see anything which is strange because, well, the data is already there.

I'm out of ideas on how to get this to show me data in more or less real time. Can anyone help?

Sharing the DAO, ViewModel and Fragment code here.

**Fragment**

```
    ... import libs and set up variables ...

    private HouseCallAdapter houseCallAdapter;

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private TextView emptyView;

    RevivDatabase revivDatabase;
    private LiveData<List<HouseCall>> liveHousecalls;
    private List<HouseCall> houseCalls;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_reviv_housecall_request_list, container, false);
        Bundle arguments = getArguments();
        String action = arguments.getString("data");
        revivDatabase = RevivDatabase.getDatabase(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        emptyView = view.findViewById(R.id.txtNoData);
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.hcrecyclerView);

        viewModel = ((Reviv) getActivity()).getViewModel();

        if(liveHousecalls == null) {
            liveHousecalls = new MutableLiveData<List<HouseCall>>();
        }


        houseCallAdapter = new HouseCallAdapter(getContext(), apikey, false, false);
        liveHousecalls = viewModel.getOpenHousecalls();

        // this is to test if there is actually any data retreived
        // calling on main thread. Lose this code later. 
        houseCalls = revivDatabase.revivDao().getHousecallsByStatus(action);
                break;



        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));

        houseCallAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {

            @Override
            public void onChanged() {
                super.onChanged();
                checkEmpty();
            }

            @Override
            public void onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
                super.onItemRangeInserted(positionStart, itemCount);
                checkEmpty();
            }

            @Override
            public void onItemRangeRemoved(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
                super.onItemRangeRemoved(positionStart, itemCount);
                checkEmpty();
            }

            void checkEmpty() {
                //emptyView.setText (R.string.no_data_available);
                emptyView.setVisibility(houseCallAdapter.getItemCount() == 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
                recyclerView.setVisibility (houseCallAdapter.getItemCount() == 0 ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        houseCallAdapter.setData(houseCalls);
        houseCallAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        liveHousecalls.observe(getActivity(), new Observer<List<HouseCall>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable List<HouseCall> houseCalls) {
                if(houseCalls != null) {
                    houseCallAdapter.setData(houseCalls);
                    houseCallAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        });

        recyclerView.setItemAnimator (new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(houseCallAdapter);
        emptyView.setVisibility(houseCallAdapter.getItemCount() == 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        return view;
    }
```

**ViewModel**

```
private LiveData<List<HouseCall>> housecallList;
    private LiveData<List<HouseCall>> openHousecalls, confirmedHousecalls, closedHousecalls, missedHousecalls, userCancelledHousecalls, respCancelledHousecalls;
    private LiveData<List<Incident>> incidentList, openIncidents;
    private LiveData<List<Incident>> closedIncidents, usercancelIncidents, respcancelIncidents;
    private LiveData<Incident> liveIncident;
    private RevivDatabase database;
    Context context;

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // CONSTRUCTOR
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public RevivViewModel(Application application) {
        super(application);
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //                                                                      //
        //      DANGER WILL ROBINSON                                            //
        //      Storing context in ViewModel is Not A Good Idea (TM)            //
        context = application.getApplicationContext();                          //
        //                                                                      //
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        database = RevivDatabase.getDatabase(application);
    }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // GETTERS AND SETTERS
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // Housecalls

    public LiveData<List<HouseCall>> getHousecallList() {
        if (housecallList == null) {
            housecallList = new MutableLiveData<>();
            loadHousecalls();
        }
        return housecallList;
    }

    public LiveData<List<HouseCall>> getOpenHousecalls() {
        if (openHousecalls == null) {
            openHousecalls = new MutableLiveData<>();
            loadOpenHousecalls();
        }
        return openHousecalls;
    }


    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // TRIGGER REFRESH FROM VIEWMODEL
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

   // TBD

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // EXTERNAL CALLS - REFRESH FROM DB
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // Methods to accept/cancel incidents and housecalls

    public void loadHousecalls(){
        class OneShotTask implements Runnable {

            OneShotTask() {
            }

            public void run() {
                housecallList = database.revivDao().getAllLiveHousecalls();
                //housecallList.postValue(hc);
            }
        }
        Thread t = new Thread(new OneShotTask());
        t.start();
    }

    public void loadOpenHousecalls(){
        class OneShotTask implements Runnable {

            OneShotTask() {
            }

            public void run() {
                openHousecalls = database.revivDao().getLiveHousecallsByStatus("open");
                                }
        }
        Thread t = new Thread(new OneShotTask());
        t.start();
    }
}
```

**DAOInterface**

```
public interface RevivDaoInterface {

    // Housecalls

    ... numerous  insert, delete and update calls ...

    @Query("SELECT * FROM housecalls WHERE housecallid = :housecallid")
    public HouseCall getHousecallById(String housecallid);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM housecalls WHERE status = :status")
    public List<HouseCall> getHousecallsByStatus(String status);

    @Update(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    void updateHousecall(HouseCall houseCall);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM housecalls WHERE status = \'open\'")
    public LiveData<List<HouseCall>> getOpenHousecalls();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM housecalls WHERE status = :status")
    public LiveData<List<HouseCall>> getLiveHousecallsByStatus(String status);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM housecalls")
    public List<HouseCall> getAllHousecalls();

}
```

**DAO**

```
imports

@Dao
public abstract class RevivDao implements RevivDaoInterface {

    @Transaction
    public void upsert(HouseCall houseCall){
        try {
            this.insert(houseCall);
        } catch (SQLiteConstraintException exception) {
            this.update(houseCall);
            Log.e(TAG, "upsert: ", exception);
        }

    }

    @Transaction
    public void upsert(List<HouseCall> houseCall){

        for(HouseCall hc : houseCall) {
            try {
                this.insert(hc);
            } catch (SQLiteConstraintException exception) {
                this.update(hc);
                Log.e(TAG, "upsert: ", exception);
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: tried to use google's [paging](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging.html) support library and create a custom [PagedListAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/paging/PagedListAdapter)?

Comment: The page says " Many apps consume data from a data source that contains a large number of items, but only display a small portion at a time.". My use-case is the opposite. This database is a personal, time-restricted view of the user's data - if they want more they can ask for it via an API Call, but the on-device data pool can't be called large by any stretch of the imagination.

Comment: did you see a working code in `PagedListAdapter` documentation? if so, whats unclear?

Comment: Taking a look now. Also, to clarify, the average size of the data in the object, reduced to JSON, is about 1.7 kb - so I don't see why I need to wait for the data to load.

Comment: if it works very fast for large data sets it will work the same with small ones too

Comment: @pskink Took a look and got the feel of the fundamental way it is supposed to help. However, while it is a great thing to have, I feel it addresses a different problem than mine -  the library divides the result into pages for gradual refresh/consumption.  My problem is that even with minimal data, I see nothing for a good while.

Comment: so you used `PagedListAdapter` and still you see nothing "for a good while"? is `LiveData<PagedList>` notified with a some delay or what?

Comment: No, I mean that I am in the process of implementing to find out if it works. I'll keep you posted :)

Comment: i dont see any reason why it wouldnt work - the whole solution is simple and easy and you dont have to reinvent the wheel

Comment: but if you want to reinvent the wheel you have to fix `loadHousecalls` method as it is basically broken (and `loadOpenHousecalls` too)

Comment: Okay, poked around and while I appreciate it for what it can do, this also means a major code rewrite for my app. Can you help me with fixing what I have, atm? I can look at adding paging in subsequent versions.

Comment: it's not major rewrite, it's a huge simplification

Comment: Can you please add how this could be done, with some code examples, or links to a few good resources that are valid / up to date?

Comment: in `PagedListAdapter` documentation you have complete, working example, did you read it? if so, what's unclear?

Comment: I tried your suggestion, and it works. Would you like to submit an answer (with a few pointers to some good articles/documentation for future reference) so I can accept it?

Comment: if you already have a working solution then simply write a self answer with your code

Comment: so is your code much more simpler than before?

Comment: Absolutely. All my worries were for nothing! This is so much easier too.

Comment: good, nice to hear it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @pskink, I figured a way around the lag in updating the data into my ViewModel.

To solve this issue, I had to implement PagedListAdapter.

**In the build.gradle (Module) file**

```
implementation 'android.arch.paging:runtime:1.0.1'
```

**In the DAO**

```
@Query("SELECT * from housecalls where status = :status")
    public abstract DataSource.Factory<Integer, HouseCall>  getHousecallPagesByStatus(String status);
```

**In the ViewModel**

```
//declare a LiveData of PagedList 
LiveData<PagedList<HouseCall>> openhousecallPages;

// Define Configuration for Paged List
Config pagedListConfig = (new PagedList.Config.Builder()).setEnablePlaceholders(true)
                .setPrefetchDistance(10)
                .setPageSize(20).build();

// Function to access the data 

public LiveData<PagedList<HouseCall>> getOpenhousecallPages(){
        openhousecallPages = new LivePagedListBuilder<>(database.revivDao().getHousecallPagesByStatus("open"),
                pagedListConfig).build();
        return openhousecallPages;
    }
```

**Set up the PagedListAdapter**

```
    package packagename;

    import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

    public class HouseCallPagedAdapter extends PagedListAdapter<HouseCall, HouseCallViewHolder>{


        protected HouseCallPagedAdapter(@NonNull DiffUtil.ItemCallback<HouseCall> diffCallback) {
            super(diffCallback);
        }

        public HouseCallPagedAdapter(@NonNull DiffUtil.ItemCallback diffcallback){
            super(diffcallback);
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public HouseCallViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int i) {
            return new HouseCallViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_housecall_request, parent, false),parent.getContext());
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull in.portmanteau.reviv.Adapters.HouseCallViewHolder holder, int i) {
            holder.bindTo(getItem(i));
        }

    }
```

**Define a ViewHolder with the following structure**

```
public class HouseCallViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
       // declare values, elements, etc

        public HouseCallViewHolder(View itemView, Context mContext) {
            super(itemView);
            // set up UI elements

        }



        void bindTo(final HouseCall houseCall){
            this.houseCall = houseCall;
            //populate values, set onClickListeners, etc. 

        }
}
```

**Finally, use the Adapter in your Activity/Fragment!**

```
// Implement an DiffUtil.ItemCallback
private DiffUtil.ItemCallback<HouseCall> diffCallback = new DiffUtil.ItemCallback<HouseCall>() {
        @Override
        public boolean areItemsTheSame(@NonNull HouseCall houseCall, @NonNull HouseCall newhouseCall) {
            return houseCall.getHousecallid().equalsIgnoreCase(newhouseCall.getHousecallid()) ;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean areContentsTheSame(@NonNull HouseCall houseCall, @NonNull HouseCall newhouseCall) {
            return houseCall.isTheSame(newhouseCall);
        }
    };
HouseCallPagedAdapter houseCallPagedAdapter = new HouseCallPagedAdapter(diffCallback);
                viewModel.getOpenhousecallPages().observe(this, houseCallPagedAdapter::submitList);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
recyclerView.setItemAnimator (new DefaultItemAnimator());
recyclerView.setAdapter(houseCallPagedAdapter);
```